# JavaFX and Windows Service - GUI crashed after logoff and then login

Tags: java, windows-services, javafx

I added my java application (using JavaFX for the GUI) as a windows service to let it keep running after logoffs. However, if I logoff once and login again, the content of the GUI is gone, I only see an empty window. The rest of the threads for processing datas still remains and works properly as I can see it from the console. The AWT tray icon is also still reactive. So I think it's a JavaFX thing. Any ideas how I can solve it?

Comment: Upgrade to the [latest released Java version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and test again if you are not currently using it.  If it still doesn't work, create a simple test case and [log an issue](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com) with the test case.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: windows xp professional sp3, jre 1.7_u21. can anyone confirm the bug?

Comment: Have you called [Platform.setImplicitExit(false)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#setImplicitExit(boolean))?

Comment: yes i already set it on false

Comment: @Wald: I also want to do the same. Would you please guide me which API you are using to make windows service and how are you communicating with Windows Service and Java Application. Thanking in anticipation

Comment: @AZ_: For java applications, use sc.exe and srvany.exe from Windows Server. First, add srvany.exe as a Windows service using sc.exe. Second, go the regedit.exe and find the key to srvany.exe where you can set up the command to launch your jar-file as if you would do it via terminal. See instructions here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890

Answer (score 0):

On XP, when you log off Session 0, your application will be notified of the event via a couple of Windows messages, WM_QUERYENDSESSION and WM_ENDSESSION. It looks like your java application will shut down in response to those. If you want your application to stay alive, you must override this behavior with some [native interface code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901609/how-to-handle-wm-queryendsession-messages-with-jna).

Comment: i called java -jar -Xrs app.jar to ignore such messages. application is actually staying alive, only the gui is somehow dead!