# log off event of Windows - Java

Tags: java, windows, jakarta-ee, logoff

I want to catch log-off event of Windows and terminate the program automatically on Logoff.

How to do it in Java?

**Details:** I have a program which runs when User logs Into Windows,and I need to stop it once the user is logs off or Locks the computer.

What should I do?

Comment: Java does not provide support for that since its VM is supposed to be a sandbox which abstracts the actual OS and its specifics. If you want to integrate such features, you´ll need to write an Windows API client in a different language that can directly talk to the API, and interface that with your Java app.

Comment: Use a Java wrapper like [commons-daemon](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html) (1) or [winrun4j](http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/) (2). But to be honest, documentation is vague: (1) appears to stop when user is logged off with option `--StartMode=java` (see [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DAEMON-203)) and (2) probably does the same with option `service.controls=session` (but I'm guessing here).

Comment: You could use JNA. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901609/how-to-handle-wm-queryendsession-messages-with-jna)