# Java Stop Windows Shutdown

Tags: java, shutdown

I have a odd problem. I want to detect when windows wants to shutdown and stop it from shutting down using java. I thought about using a shutdown hook and just run a command shutdown /a however it doesnt seem to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to respond to the [`WM_QUERYENDSESSION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/wm-queryendsession) message and return 0.

You can do it with [JNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901609/how-to-handle-wm-queryendsession-messages-with-jna).

Another example here: https://github.com/mirror/jdownloader/blob/656fe1fdc9689ffe4067a2cab3bf11c54bbaf25d/src/org/jdownloader/osevents/windows/jna/ShutdownDetect.java

```
package org.jdownloader.osevents.windows.jna;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import org.appwork.utils.swing.windowmanager.WindowManager;
import org.appwork.utils.swing.windowmanager.WindowManager.FrameState;

import com.sun.jna.Callback;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.DWORD;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LPARAM;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LRESULT;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.WPARAM;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser;

public class ShutdownDetect {
    /**
     * @see <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376889.aspx">WM_ENDSESSION reference</a>
     */
    public static final int WM_ENDSESSION      = 0x16;
    public static final int WM_QUERYENDSESSION = 0x11;

    public interface IShutdownListener {
        void onShutdown();
    }

    public static class CWPSSTRUCT extends Structure {
        public LPARAM lParam;
        public WPARAM wParam;
        public DWORD  message;
        public HWND   hwnd;

        @Override
        protected List getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "lParam", "wParam", "message", "hwnd" });
        }
    }

    public interface WinHookProc extends WinUser.HOOKPROC {
        /**
         * @see <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644975(v=vs.85).aspx">CallWndProc callback function</a>
         * @param nCode
         *            is an action parameter. anything less than zero indicates I should ignore this call.
         * @param wParam
         *            Specifies whether the message was sent by the current thread. If the message was sent by the current thread, it is
         *            nonzero; otherwise, it is zero
         * @param hookProcStruct
         *            A pointer to a CWPSTRUCT structure that contains details about the message.
         * @return If nCode is less than zero, the hook procedure must return the value returned by CallNextHookEx.
         */
        WinDef.LRESULT callback(int nCode, WinDef.WPARAM wParam, CWPSSTRUCT hookProcStruct);
    }

    public static final class MyHookProc implements WinHookProc {
        public IShutdownListener listener;
        public WinUser.HHOOK     hhook;

        @Override
        public LRESULT callback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, CWPSSTRUCT hookProcStruct) {
            if (nCode >= 0) {
                System.out.println(hookProcStruct.message);
                // tell the OS it's OK to shut down
                if (hookProcStruct.message.longValue() == WM_QUERYENDSESSION) {
                    System.out.println("WM_QUERYENDSESSION");
                    return new LRESULT(1);
                }
                // process the actual shutting down message
                if (hookProcStruct.message.longValue() == WM_ENDSESSION) {
                    System.out.println("WM_ENDSESSION");
                    listener.onShutdown();
                    return new LRESULT(0); // return success
                }
            }
            // pass the callback on to the next hook in the chain
            return User32.INSTANCE.CallNextHookEx(hhook, nCode, wParam, hookProcStruct.getPointer());
        }
    }

    public static void register(JFrame frame, final IShutdownListener listener) {
        Native.setCallbackExceptionHandler(new Callback.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Callback arg0, Throwable arg1) {
                arg1.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        // get the window handle for the main window/frame
        final HWND hwnd = new HWND();
        hwnd.setPointer(Native.getComponentPointer(frame));

        // clear the error value
        Native.setLastError(0);

        // retrieve the threadID associated with the main window/frame
        int windowThreadID = User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, null);
        if (windowThreadID == 0) {
            int x = Native.getLastError();
            throw new IllegalStateException("error calling GetWindowThreadProcessId when installing machine-shutdown handler " + x);
        }

        // clear the error value
        Native.setLastError(0);

        final MyHookProc proc = new MyHookProc();
        proc.listener = listener;
        proc.hhook = User32.INSTANCE.SetWindowsHookEx(4/* WH_CALLWNDPROCRET */, new MyHookProc(), null, windowThreadID/* dwThreadID */);

        // null indicates failure
        if (proc.hhook == null) {
            int x = Native.getLastError();
            throw new IllegalStateException("error calling SetWindowsHookEx when installing machine-shutdown handler " + x);
        }
        System.out.println("Installed shutdown-detect hook procedure");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Shutdown Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        WindowManager.getInstance().setVisible(frame, true,FrameState.OS_DEFAULT);

        // register(frame, new IShutdownListener() {
        // @Override
        // public void onShutdown() {
        // try {
        // File file;
        // PrintStream out = new PrintStream(file = new File("C:/shutdownTest.txt"));
        // System.out.println("shutting down");
        // out.println("shutting down");
        // out.close();
        // } catch (IOException ex) {
        // }
        // System.exit(1);
        // }
        // });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am fairly new to java coming from c#. With my research does this mean it would stop execution of my java program when this is being called? I imagine ill need to figure out a way to recover from a user trying to shutdown the system.

Comment: It's up to you to terminate or not to terminate the program during message handling. You can return 0, ask Windows to stop the shut down, and then just do nothing to your program so it continues.

Comment: The code has changed: https://github.com/mirror/jdownloader/blob/5f50ef81a535c64d31713ed043587eac7a3da057/src/org/jdownloader/osevents/multios/SignalEventSource.java

Answer (score 1):

After battling with this problem few weeks and finally solving it i wanted to share the code here. Here is minimal example using java 1.8 and JNA 5.13.0 (also platform).

TIP: I had problem using this code first (unsatisfied links). I discovered i had library (jar file) on my JDK which had older JNA in it. Make sure you only have 1 version of JNA in your project.

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.*;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.*;
import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIOptions;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;

public class RealShutdownBlocker {
private static final int WM_QUERYENDSESSION = 0x0011;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User32 user32 = Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

        WindowProc callback = new WindowProc() {
            public LRESULT callback(HWND hWnd, int message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
                if (message == WM_QUERYENDSESSION) {
                    return new LRESULT(0);
                }
                return user32.DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        };
        
        WNDCLASSEX windowClass = new WNDCLASSEX();
        windowClass.hInstance = null;
        windowClass.lpszClassName = "BlockShutdown";
        windowClass.lpfnWndProc = callback;
        user32.RegisterClassEx(windowClass);

        HWND hwnd = user32.CreateWindowEx(0, "BlockShutdown", "This prevents windows shutdown", WinUser.WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 100, 640,
                480, null, null, null, null);

        // needs to be SW_SHOW for this to work
        user32.ShowWindow(hwnd, WinUser.SW_SHOW);

        MSG msg = new MSG();
        while (user32.GetMessage(msg, null, 0, 0) != 0) {
            user32.TranslateMessage(msg);
            user32.DispatchMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: No need for kernel32. Deleted it.

Comment: interesting, but please add POM/classpath/jars you used to compile this code.

Comment: https://github.com/java-native-access/jna Here you can download jna and jna-platform. I used latest (5.13.0 currently). I added them to my project with eclipse by "Add jars" But you could do it by just adding them to your POM

Comment: Also loadLibrary() is deprecated but still kept. Can be changed to load() without problems.

Answer (score 0):

In newer JDK versions you can now use [Desktop::disableSuddenTermination](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Desktop.html#disableSuddenTermination()) from the AWT API to prevent Windows logout / shutdown / restart. That'll make it return `FALSE` in response to the `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` message. See [awt_Toolkit.cpp](https://github.com/JetBrains/JetBrainsRuntime/blob/8845e3aa8ada1562db459cdb92ca62f1839158f3/src/java.desktop/windows/native/libawt/windows/awt_Toolkit.cpp#L1314) for implementation details.