# Make java program to "Application x prevents shutdown" in windows

Tags: java, windows, jvm, shutdown

When we shutdown windows, sometimes it shows some warnings such that "Application x prevents shutdown"

I am currently developing a java exe application with javafx. How can I make my java program to prevent shutdown like that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Stop Windows Shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61017025/java-stop-windows-shutdown)

Comment: @Turamarth I tried to catch  WM_QUERYENDSESSION message with suggested way but most of the time my program  directly shuts down without catching that message, so that did not help me

Comment: [That’s how you do it with AWT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Desktop.html#setQuitHandler(java.awt.desktop.QuitHandler)) But you may not want to mix JavaFX with AWT…

Comment: hope this can help you https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1257858/How-to-get-shutdown-event-in-windows-from-java-app